# Взлом защиты на основе виртуальной машины

Tags: защита

У нас в исследовательском проекте возникла необходимость разработать систему защиты кода. Цель защиты - сокрытие кода (алгоритма) от воспроизведения. Код - библиотека на чистом С (там нет вызовов функций из внешних библиотек). Одна из необычных идей - написать компилятор из С в какой-нибудь экзотический язык, например, BrainFuck, сделать виртуальную машину для этого языка и запускать библиотеку на нем.

Вопрос. Если бы перед вами стояла задача взлома подобной системы, как бы вы действовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что собственно пытаетесь защитить? Какова цель защиты?
Если пытаемся защитить алгоритм закодированный на С от плагиата, то виртуальная машина, пусть на Брэйнфаке, все равно воспроизведет действия алгоритма(в каком-то виде).
Если пытаемся защитить скомпилированный бинарник от внесения изменений в его работу, то тут чем проще ассемблер, тем подарочнее хакеру, а у брейнфака очень простой ассемблер.
Чето на этом моя фантазия заканчивается)

Comment: Задача - предельно затруднить понимание алгоритма работы кода.

Comment: Если задача действительно в том, чтоб скрыть какой-то ценный(принципиально новый, к примеру) алгоритм, то для исследовательского проекта на мой взгляд надо думать в сторону Malbolge, точнее в сторону его ключевых отличий от brainfuck.

Comment: Но везде есть свои плюсы-минусы:
Найти виртуальную машину в исполняемом коде не проблема: это цикл с длинным switch-case, в котором программа проводит большую часть времени. Если ассеблер ВМ такой же замороченый как у Malbolge - то бинго. Если нет, тогда найти байт-код вашего алгоритма не проблема и понять его тоже можно, я думаю, при сильном желании. А желание должно быть сильным, так как понять код неизвестного алгоритма даже написанном на С - это сама по себе проблема не маленькая.

Comment: Вообще есть живой пример упрятывания алгоритмов - это Skype. Для защиты используется комбинация антиотладочных приемов и шифрования.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю стоит обратить внимание на [Malbolge](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge).

))))))

У этого языка есть два существенных отличия от брейнфака:

- использование троичной системы
- шифрование

Comment: Забавный язык. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если защищается передаваемый пользователю бинарник, то чтобы затруднить взлом кода конкурентами, достаточно эффективно вставлять фрагменты с самомодифицирующимся кодом, изменяющим ветвление на неточно работающий фрагмент (грубую ошибку легче отловить) в передаваемом бинарнике на верное. Если правильно работающий фрагмент быстро возвратит код в исходное состояние, то  по дампу реассемблированный код (взятый на реассемблирование даже после некоторого периода работы модулей ПО) будет содержать ту же ошибку.

Если текст ПО как встарь по ЕСПД нехороший заказчик получает в исходном виде, и сам проводит сборку, то выше указанные действия может выполнять модуль обработки прерывания ошибки, вызванной, например, заменой английской "с" на русскую "с".

Есть и более сложные динамически выполняемые приемы. Но лучшая защита - быстрее делать новое, более функциональное и качественное ПО.  Microsoft, и не он один, похоже идет по этому пути, со своими частыми сервиспаками и новыми версиями...

Comment: Никогда не думал, что Microsoft, используя обновления, защищает свой продукт от взлома. А ведь в этом что-то есть. :-)